# How to display a rapidly changing image in libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

Is there any way to display new pictures every frame in LibGDX that doesn't call a new texture object every frame as it takes so long?

I need to draw a new image on each frame, but if I translate this image into a Pixmap from which the texture is created, then the fps drops from 4000-5000 frames to 40-60. Moreover, the transfer of the image from the BufferedImage to the Pixmap does not take so long, and the creation of the Texture object is completed very slowly.

Comment: Draw to a FrameBuffer instead of a Pixmap. You can get the color buffer texture from the FrameBuffer to draw into your scene.